# How do I capture output of the following command: 'gh workflow run <ID>'?

Tags: bash, github, stdout, stderr

I am trying to capture output of the 'gh' command line tool.

(Assuming my workflow action ID is '16744616')

When running the command:

```
$ gh workflow run 16744616
```

I get following output:

```
✓ Created workflow_dispatch event for manual_test_mv_windows.yml at master

To see runs for this workflow, try: gh run list --workflow=manual_test_mv_windows.yml
```

But, when I tried to capture the output:

```
$ MYVAR=$( gh workflow run 16744616 )
$ echo $MYVAR
```

The output is empty.

Tried into a file (both STDERR and STDOUT):

```
$ gh workflow run 16744616 &> output.txt
```

The file is empty.

Comment: Is `gh` an alias, function, or script that expands to something else? Also, the formatting makes it tricky to tell if `$ MYVAR=$(...) $ echo $MYVAR` was two separate commands, including prompts, or something else. Can you use the curly braces or three-backtick code fencing to demonstrate your input and output?

Comment: Could you validate if the same happens with `gh --version`?

Comment: The 'gh' is a command line tool, please see: https://cli.github.com/

Comment: Regarding 'gh --version': 
$ gh --version; 
OUTPUT:
gh version 2.11.3 (2022-05-25)
https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.11.3

$ MYVAR=$( gh --version );
$ echo $MYVAR;
OUTPUT captured into variable:
gh version 2.11.3 (2022-05-25) https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.11.3
- Seems OK

Comment: I would also like an answer to this question. I agree that when doing `test=$(gh --version)` then the output gets captured in the variable test. But for all other standard usages of `gh` then it just doesn't work. I, too, cannot capture the output in any way.

Comment: Also, please don't use quotes for any kind of code - it displays badly. I've replaced all of them with code blocks for you.

Comment: They added `--silent` flag

Answer (score 4):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/604adc57efd7d98b560c4abf4b33f2241ad839e0/pkg/cmd/workflow/run/run.go#L314), `gh workflow run` command only produces output when the STDOUT is a terminal, so this question literally turns into [How to trick a command into thinking its output is going to a terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249723/211239).

One of the answers mentioned something I've been using for long: `unbuffer`.

So I did this:

```bash
VAR="$(unbuffer gh workflow run 114514)"
```

Note that `unbuffer` does not usually come pre-installed on a typical Linux distro. On Ubuntu and Debian, you need `apt install expect` first.

Comment: Seems interesting. Do you have any idea though how this can work on windows? Since 'unbuffered' is not supported in bash on windows as far as I can tell (I tried it...)

Comment: @EyalGerber Check that question. On Bash on Windows (Windows Subsystem for Linux), you need to `apt install expect` to get the `unbuffer` command.

Comment: `apt install expect` does not work in Windows. I can use chocolatey but I see that there is no such package for 'expect' in chocolatey. So I found that expect does exist in cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/packages/summary/expect.html) so I installed it through cygwin but still the `unbuffer` command is not recognized even in the cygwin terminal following the installation of 'expect'. Any other ideas?

Comment: @EyalGerber Sorry but what exactly do you mean "Bash on Windows"? Other than WSL it's not commonly referring to anything else.

Comment: sorry for not explaining properly. Bash on windows in the end is just an executable of bash.exe or git-bash.exe which can be installed via multiple tools such as cygwin, mysys etc. If added to path it can be used in any terminal on Windows such as power shell, cmd.exe, mysys terminal, cygwin terminal, git-bash terminal etc. The objective is to be able to run the `gh` command of GitHub CLI and store its output in a variable when running a bash script on Windows. So if `unbuffer` command is to be used on Windows I must have a way to properly install it and refer to it from a bash script.

Comment: @EyalGerber While I coundn't find the `unbuffer` command from [Cygwin `expect` package](https://www.cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/expect/expect-5.45-3), there is one in [MSYS2](https://packages.msys2.org/package/expect?repo=msys&variant=x86_64) which is also the default environment for Git Bash. You could give MSYS2 a try if you need, though I personally only use WSL now.

Comment: indeed with MSYS2 it worked! Thanks so much for the help! I will grant you the bounty!

Comment: I tried using this on ubuntu, but all I got was a gibberish output.